# Azure App Service - Some WebAPI methods throw OWIN Exception

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, owin, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile App that has some methods that generate 500 errors but does not record any exceptions in Application Insights and no exceptions are thrown inside my code.  I have been able to determine that normal TableController methods work fine, but custom methods do not.  Also, I can remote debug the code and watch it finish executing without any exceptions being thrown.  It should also be noted that I did not have this problem when this project was a Mobile Service.  Here is an example method that fails:

```
    private readonly MobileServiceContext context; //Autofac injection
    private readonly IUserHelper userHelper; //Autofac injection

    [HttpGet, Route("api/Site/{id}/Users")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Users(string id)
    {
        var userId = await userHelper.GetUserIdAsync(User, Request);
        var query = context.UserSiteMaps.Include(x => x.User).Where(map => map.SiteId == id);
        var auth = query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.IsAdmin);
        if (auth != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, query.Select(map => map.User));
        }
        return Request.CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
    }
```

The deepest error log that I have been able to obtain is the detailed error page from IIS:

Module     __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_9de2321b-e781-4017-8ff3-4acd1e48b129
Notification       PreExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code
   0x00000000

I haven't been able to generate a more detailed error message and I have no idea what Owin is upset about here since other method return requests just fine.  Am I doing something I shouldn't?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update** : Here is the full error message that I have been able to get.
[image: Full Error Message]

I have also been able to narrow the cause down a bit.  If I replace the `query.Select(map => map.User)` object in the response with a simple string, it returns that string without complaint.  However, if I stringify the response myself and pass that in, I get 500s again.  Could it be some serializer setting problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track down the issue is to turn on exception stack traces for you app and to turn on logging on your Mobile App backend.

See [Server Side Logging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#server-side-logging) in the Mobile Apps wiki and [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/). You can also remote debug your service to see the exact error, see [Remote debugging .NET server SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#remote-debugging-net-server-sdk).

Comment: I have detailed logging enabled, both in the web.config and in the Azure portal as described in your links, however I have never been able to get an actual stack trace.  I will put the whole error message into my question.   This 500 error is the only thing that shows up in the Log stream and I've flipped every detailed logging switch I can find.

Comment: Try using Visual Studio to debug the App Service - you can attach a debugger using the Cloud Explorer.